# jQuery Coda Slider: javascript error in IE8 only

Tags: jquery, coda-slider

I'm getting a javascript error when using coda slider in IE8:

```
"Expected ']'"
```

Weird thing is that it only triggers when I put it online. If I use the localhost version of the site, nothing happens.

The error occurs when using:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="$.prettyPhoto.open(
 [\''.implode('\',\'',$pp['gallery']['link']).'\'],
 [\''.implode('\',\'',$pp['gallery']['title']).'\'],
 [\''.implode('\',\'',$pp['gallery']['description']).'\']
);">gallery</a>';
```

any ideas?

Comment: Heavens! That thing's a Gordian Knot! I think by trying to echo a string, you're only complicating things. You basically have three layers of execution in there: the echo, the string-builder making the onclick event, and then the onclick event itself. I'd take a big step back, reassess what it is you're trying to do and start over.

Comment: gordian knot? it is very simple. the problem was that some of the $pp vars had simple quotes inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is one of your variables having a simple quote ?

Comment: you saved my day. it seems someone already inserting news in the live site is using quotes and i'm not controlling it. thanks!

Comment: mmm im now converting simple quotes to &#039; but the javascript error remains :s if i delete the simple quotes, all problems dissapear. shouldn't it work when replacing the quotes?

Comment: `strInput.replace("'","\\'");`
Note the double backslash. Because of your nesting, you may have to add additional layers of escaping -- just add another backslash until it works.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i preferred to sanitize the string server side: $data = str_replace('\'','"',$data);return htmlspecialchars($data,ENT_QUOTES);